# mysql: list number of orders all customers made

Tags: mysql

I have 2 simple tables like customers and orders where a customer can have 0 to n orders. I would like to have a list like:
10 customers made 0 orders
4 customers made 1 order
5 customers made 2 orders
2 customers made 3 orders
... and so on. So far I have:

```
SELECT customers.id FROM customers
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.customerId = customers.id
HAVING COUNT(orders.id) = 1;
```

which lists me all customers who made 1 order, but as I said I need a list with all possebilities.

Comment: Sorry: Users are the customers.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Comment: You know, this is kind of simple. Can you really not figure out how to adapt what you already have? Hint: you're missing a GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), t.orderCount
FROM
(
    SELECT u.id, COUNT(o.id) AS orderCount
    FROM users u LEFT JOIN orders o
        ON u.id = o.userId
    GROUP BY u.id
) t
GROUP BY t.orderCount
```

The inner query will give each user and his order total:

```
user total
  1   2
  2   3
  3   2
  4   3
```

The outer query does a `GROUP BY` this total to count the number of customers who share the total:

```
# customers  total
     2         2
     2         3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate function and group bu

```
SELECT ifnull(count(orders.id),0), users.id FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.userId = users.id
group by users.id
```